# AWS CloudFormation drop down for IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to select an IAM Role from the list to attach it to EC2 instances while deploying servers. However, I'm not seeing an option to do this.

```
"IAMRole": {
            "Description": "EC2 attached IAM role, must be an existing IAM role which will be attached to EC2 instance.",
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role::RoleName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be the name of an existing IAM Role",
        },
```

I'm only having an option to use `Type: String` and pass default string value.

Correct me if this is wrong or something I need to know.

Comment: Please post your CF template.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Parameters - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), there is **no parameter type** for nominating an IAM Role.

There are pre-defined types for VPC, Subnets, Security Groups, etc but none for IAM elements.

Therefore, it is not possible to present an automatically-populated drop-down list of IAM Roles when selecting parameters during the launch of an AWS CloudFormation stack.